# How do I get the last day of the quarter date using Date and ceiling?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, ceil

I want to get the date that is the last day of the quarter. Can you help me solve this?

I've taken over an old model and trying to understand the logic behind it. The quarter end date is formulated as follows:
`A2=DATE(Year(A1),CEILING(MONTH(A1),3)+1,0)` Where cell `A1=2019-07-01.`
This formula= 2019-09-30 which is the right date, but I'm having a hard time understanding the ceiling, multiplier and `+1`. I think the `+1` is to get September (9) instead of August (8) but I don't understand why 3 as a multiplier returns 8 if it is not a multiplier of 3. Shouldn't it return 6 or 9?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes it would be clearer nowadays to use eomonth -  which has been around since Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this into parts:

- `MONTH(A1)`: equals 7.
- `CEILING(7,3)`: equals 9.
- `CEILING(7,3)+1`: equals 10.
- `YEAR(A1)`: equals 2019.
- `DATE(2019, 10, 0)`: equals 2019-09-30.

Using `0` as the day with `DATE` is the trick - October "0th" is actually September 30th.